# PREG_MATCH getting data from string

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I would like to get everything except all between 'TERMIN' [...] and 'html' :

'wordings wordings wordings TERMIN AL2HaIbYzmY.html wordings wordings'

My code only give me things between TERMIN and html... i am getting dumb

```
    preg_match('#TERMIN(.*)html#is',$url,$url);
$url = $url[count($url)-1];
```

Comment: Be more descriptive of your problem, your current results and your expected results. This code makes no sense on its own.

Comment: preg_match('#(.*)kto(.*)html(.*)#is',$kto_element_url,$kto_element_url);
 $kto_element_url = $kto_element_url[1].' '.$kto_element_url[3];

 echo '<br />'.$kto_element_url;

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do something like this:

```
$str = 'wordings wordings wordings TERMIN AL2HaIbYzmY.html wordings wordings';
preg_match('/(?P<part1>.*TERMIN )(.*\.)(?<part2>html.*)/i', $str, $result);
echo $result['part1'].$result['part2'];
```

But this is very strict solution as you gave only one "example".

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('#TERMIN(.*)html#is',$url,$out);
$url = $out[1]
```

$out[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $out[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Or for all matches to the regular expression

```
preg_match_all('#TERMIN(.*)html#is',$url,$out,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

$out[0][1], $out[1][1], $out[2][1] ...